# Comparing 2 xml files using XMLUnit jar of java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have 2 xml files as like below,

Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Email>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>sender</from>
    <CC>A</CC>
    <CC>B</CC>
    <CC>C</CC>
    <CC>D</CC>
    <CC>E</CC>
    <CC>F</CC>
</Email>
```

Reference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Email>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>sender</from>
    <CC>B</CC>
    <CC>C</CC>
    <CC>D</CC>
    <CC>E</CC>
    <CC>F</CC>
</Email>
```

**Note: The difference between both the files is A (not exist in Reference.xml)**

I have used the following code to get the difference from the files,

```
Diff diff = new Diff(InputDocument, ReferenceDocument);
DetailedDiff detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
List<Difference> diffList = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
```

Here the difference List is having more than one difference but the actual difference is only one node. I understand that this is happened due to one to one match (like comparing A from Input.xml file with B of Reference.xml, which results in difference of node and the next B of Input.xml is compared with C of Reference.xml and so on).

My requirement is that the difference list should contain only one difference as like (Expected node A but was null). So that I can process the actual difference further for my application.

How can I make this to fulfil my requirement?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Whitespace is still text content, and they have to be represented. What was the erroneous diffList's contents?

Comment: I would suggest you use an XSD file and a Schema Validator rather than a reference XML file.

Comment: @nitind : Yes you are right nitind. The whitespaces can be ignored by configuring XMLUnit. There is no error in diffList's content but i wanted it to have only one actual difference instead of having many differences due to one to one compare. Any possibilities for the requirement with XMLUnit?

Comment: @Sameer Puri: Will it fulfill my requirement? Actually I am not sure about XSD file and schema validator. Can you provide me any links to know about it elaborately?

Comment: I don't really know XMLUnit, but this would just be a simple String assertion in JUnit.